# Why doesn't my numpad work right in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-layout

In several terminal programs, such as [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)), [SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/), [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), and Mac OS Terminal,
if I have NumLock on and I press the number pad (numpad) keys `0123456789` in insert mode, my vim looks like this:

```
y                                                                                                          
x
w
v
u
t
s
r
q
p

~
```

If I use the numpad on the command line, it enters the numbers I expect.

How do I make vim type the right characters from the numpad?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Short answer

Turn off “application keypad mode switching.”

#### Terminal-specific instructions

- [PuTTY](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings#Using_the_numeric_keypad)) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7284745/1144854)):
  `Terminal > Features > uncheck Disable application keypad mode`
- SecureCRT:
  `Session Options > Terminal > Emulation > Modes > Mode switching > uncheck Enable keypad mode switching`
- iTerm: Switch to iTerm2 or see general instructions below.
- [iTerm2](https://www.twistermc.com/39930/use-number-pad-vim-iterm2/) (also [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131110033808/https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=1357)):
  `Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Load Preset… > xterm with Numeric Keypad` or add the settings manually as shown [here](https://superuser.com/a/939832/163315).
- [Mac OS Terminal](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6613968) (also [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201341/201023)):
  `Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > uncheck Allow VT100 application keypad mode`
- Other: look for an option like `application keypad mode` or see below.

#### General instructions for .vimrc

If the terminal-specific instructions don't work for you, you can fix it in vim by adding the following mappings to your `.vimrc`:

```
:inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
:inoremap <Esc>Or 2
:inoremap <Esc>Os 3
:inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
:inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
:inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
:inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
:inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
:inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
:inoremap <Esc>Op 0
:inoremap <Esc>On .
:inoremap <Esc>OQ /
:inoremap <Esc>OR *
:inoremap <Esc>Ol +
:inoremap <Esc>OS -
:inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

Comment: The fundamental question is: why does Vim enable Keypad Application Mode without mapping the resulting function-key input to something? (Either digit input or the typical cursor movement and scrolling keys.) Why do all these terminal emulators have to have a way to ignore the enable-KAM command?

Answer (score 0):

SecureCRT, Options> Session Options> Terminal> Emulation>Modes>

Initial Modes and Current Modes sections, select Numeric keypad.

I found my Current modes was set to Application keypad when I wanted Numeric keypad to be default.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It would improve this answer to [edit] and explain _what_ terminal this concerns and what the difference between "Application keypad" and "Numeric keypad" is.